# Parsing contents of S3 bucket to local MySQL database in PHP

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have been tasked with trying to connect a local MySQL database, to an S3 bucket, and to read and return the contents of the bucket, but have no idea where to begin. I have my access keys but don't really know what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following project uses S3 to upload files. I'm not sure if they have a method to retrieve objects from S3. but at least is a start.

```
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel
```

If not, a quick search on Packagist for "S3" brought me to this project:

```
https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class
```

This one has methods that might help you such as:

```
S3::getBucket($bucketName)
S3::getObject($bucketName, $uploadName)
```